# Values to variables mentioned in variables.tf in Terraform through environment variables file .tfvars

Tags: terraform

How do I pass the values of variables mentioned in `variable.tf` of type "list" or "map" . Are there any mistakes in the syntax in the `input.tfvars` file mentioned below?

The goal is not to hard code any values in the `variables.tf` or the `main.tf` file. In the `Terraform.io` docs I verified that the values can be provided in this format.

This is from the site:
Lists are defined either explicitly or implicitly:

```
 # implicitly by using brackets [...]
 variable "cidrs" { default = [] }

 # explicitly
 variable "cidrs" { type = "list" }
```

You can specify lists in a the `terraform.tfvars` file:

```
 cidrs = [ "10.0.0.0/16", "10.1.0.0/16" ]
```

Now, when I try to do

```
terraform plan -var-file=input.tfvars
```

it is unable to read the variable values from the tfvars file and presents the following error:

> Error: module root:
>   module vpc: required variable "vpccidr" not set
>   module vpc: required variable "vpcname" not set

The `variables.tf` file looks like:

```
variable "vpccidr" { type = "list"}
variable "vpcname" { type = "list" }
```

The `input.tfvars` file looks like:

```
vpccidr=[ "10.1.0.0/16", "10.2.0.0/16", "10.3.0.0/16" ]
vpcname=[ "vpc1", "vpc2", "vpc3" ]
```

The `main.tf` file looks like:

```
module "vpc"{
  source = "modules/network/vpc"
}
```

The VPC module under `modules/network` has the following configuration file `main.tf` and the variable file mentioned above in `variables.tf`:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "customVpc" {
  count = "${length(var.vpccidr)}"
  cidr_block = "${element(var.vpccidr, count.index)}"
  tags {
    count = "${length(var.vpcname)}"
    Name = "${element(var.vpcname, count.index)}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Upon debugging i found out that if i move the  do not call the module and explicitly create the resource  in the main.tf  under the main folder it works file . I can input the values of the variables in input.tfvars and works fine .

Comment: Only when i use the module "vpc" in the main.tf is when it does not read the values from the input.tfvars  but expects the values to be hard coded in the variables.tf file   ..   This is the directory structure

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variables to your module, i.e

```
module "vpc"{
  source = "modules/network/vpc"

  vpccidr = "${var.vpccidr}"
  vpcname = "${var.vpcname}"
}
```

Comment: Well i want to have only one variable.tf file  defined. If i specify in the main folder  and not in the modules folder  i get an error                                                                    
Error: resource 'aws_vpc.customVpc' count: unknown variable referenced: 'vpccidr'; define it with a 'variable' block.       and same happens if i specify a variable.tf in modules folder and remove it from the main folder

Comment: It works only  if i have a variable.tf file  in both main and modules folders with variable names "vpccdir" and "vpcname" .  That should not be case right .   Any resolution .

Comment: The reason i am asking is i want to create different folders unders modules for each resource ( vpc,subnet,storage,sg,elb etc) and call this modules from the main folders ( for dev , prod ,stage ) . So it become cumbersome to have variables.tf file in each of the modules folder and also in main folder

Comment: @kathir unfortunately, that is what you need to do. Think of each module like a standalone function that accepts parameters (via variables) - if you don't pass the parameters to the function, then it doesn't know what they are

Comment: \@rwisch45 Thank you for your responses . Yes it is challenging researching and exploring which works and which does not .  Shouldnt there be something like Global variables - define once and be done with that . In a production scale  IaC workload managing so many variable files is a nightmare .

Comment: @kathir Well, I would disagree with the concept of Global variables. Each variable is a bit of complexity, but a global variable adds complexity to the whole program (because it may have effects all over the program, hence the name), while a local variable adds complexity only in a single isolated unit, the function.
You wouldn't want to change a single function/variable and cause a totally different part of the program to fail. Each global variable increases this risk.

Comment: @kathir Passing through every top level variable to each of your modules would be a nightmare indeed. To combat this, we can use sensible conventions to use default values for variables within our modules. We can also nest modules into logical groupings, i.e web-app module could contain modules for a database, load balancer, and web server. That type of structure can help us see even more patterns of re-use and sensible variable defaults and conventions.