# Unable to reference vpc_id for a subnet within modules

Tags: terraform

Have a modules/network/testvpc and modules/network/subnet module configurations .

## mainfolder/modules/network/testvpc/main.tf

```
    variable "vpccidr" {type="list"}
    variable "vpcname" {type="list"}

   resource "aws_vpc" "customVpc" {
   count = "${length(var.vpccidr)}"
   cidr_block = "${element(var.vpccidr,count.index)}"

    tags {
    Name = "${element(var.vpcname,count.index)}"
    }
```

## mainfolder/modules/network/subnet/main.tf

```
variable "subcidr" {type="list"}
variable "subname" {type="list"}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
count = "${length(var.subcidr)}"
vpc_id = "${element(aws_vpc.customVpc.*.id, count.index)}"
cidr_block = "${element(var.subcidr, count.index)}"

tags {

Name = "${element(var.subname, count.index)}"
}
 }
```

## mainfolder/main.tf

```
module "testvpc" {
source = "./modules/network/testvpc"
vpccidr="${var.vpccidr}"
vpcname="${var.vpcname}"
}

module "subnet" {
source = "./modules/network/subnet"
subcidr = "${var.subcidr}"
subname = "${var.subname}"
}
```

## mainfolder/var.tf

```
  variable "vpccidr" {type="list"}
  variable "vpcname" {type="list"}
  variable "subcidr" {type="list"}
  variable "subname" {type="list"}
```

## mainfolder/terraform.tfvars

```
 - vpccidr=["10.1.0.0/16","10.2.0.0/16","10.3.0.0/16"]   
   vpcname=["vpc-shared","vpc-sand","vpc-preprod"]   
   subcidr=["10.1.1.0/24","10.2.1.0/24","10.3.1.0/24"]   
   subname=["sub-shared","sub-sand","sub-preprod"]
 -
```

While running terraform validate -var-file=terraform.tfvars getting the following error

```
            Error: resource 'aws_subnet.subnet' config: unknown 
           resource 'data.aws_vpc.customVpc' referenced in variable 
           data.aws_vpc.customVpc.*.id
```

Is it because aws_subnet is not able to locate vpc_id  since the resource aws_vpc is not created it . I am calling both the testvpc and subnet as modules in the mainfolder/main.tf  . What am i missing .

Secondly is the loop in the aws_vpc and aws_subnet proper . It should create vpc-shared  10.1.0.0/16 and sub-shared within that vpc and so on

Comment: Also tried mentioning  "data"   vpc_id = "${element(data.aws_vpc.customVpc.*.id, count.index)}"     but did not help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [module outputs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html#outputs) because you are trying to reference resources in a separate module. That won't work because

> Modules encapsulate their resources. A resource in one module cannot directly depend on resources or attributes in other modules, unless those are exported through outputs.

So in **mainfolder/modules/network/testvpc/main.tf**, add an output like so

```
output "vpc_ids" { value=["${aws_vpc.customVpc.*.id}"] }
```

Then add a variable in **mainfolder/modules/network/subnet/main.tf** like so

```
variable "vpc_ids" {type="list"}
```

and use it within that module (instead of trying to directly reference resources from the **/testvpc/main.tf** module)

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  count = "${length(var.subcidr)}"
  vpc_id = "${element(var.vpc_ids, count.index)}"

  etc, etc

}
```

and finally now from your **mainfolder/main.tf**

```
module "testvpc" {
  source = "./modules/network/testvpc"
  vpccidr="${var.vpccidr}"
  vpcname="${var.vpcname}"
}

module "subnet" {
  source = "./modules/network/subnet"
  subcidr = "${var.subcidr}"
  subname = "${var.subname}"
  vpc_ids = "${module.testvpc.vpc_ids}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @rwisch45 . Let me try that . Also as i increase my resources ( route table , internet gw etc ) by way of modules  i need to mention vpc_id in all those main.tf files . Is there a better way, something like global variables ( one stop ) for all the variable values referenced in mainfolder as well as modules . Becomes easier to maintain from a administration perspective

Comment: @kathir don't think so, but that gets back into the discussion we were having on your [other terraform question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52486922/values-to-variables-mentioned-in-variables-tf-in-terraform-through-environment-v)

Comment: Was able to specify outputs and it worked . Thank @rwisch45 . While creating internet gw in the loop context and assing a vpc_id variable the gw was attached to the 10.1.0.0/16 vpc .  What is the logic . The last VPC which was created was vpc0 ?    So i am wondering what if i want to attach the gw to two vpc   . How do i do that while still maintaining the loop